# Получить A+ на ssllabs OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107

Tags: ssl, openssl

Всем привет! Не могу добиться А+ от своего SSL - а получаю только F!
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=intestenergo.ru
Делал по этому принципу https://toster.ru/q/239974 и не только. Всё равно F.

И вроде всё более-менее только за Protocol Support - 0 и я так понимаю это из-за  OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107 как его побороть, нет соображений?

Comment: Тут всё норм https://filippo.io/Heartbleed/#intestenergo.ru

Comment: пробил 
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Походу надо как-то обновить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил OpenSSL, перезагрузил сервер, сделал новый ключ - получил А+

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/89944)

Comment: @cheops будьте внимательнее, пожалуйста. Это авторский ответ, а не дополнение к вопросу.